# Alfresco : How to search a mimeType of file using 'lucensearch'

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I have written the following javascirpt code snipped in **Alfresco CMS** to find and print  names of files whose  **mimetype is "image/png"** into a book.txt file. This code creates the book.txt file successfully, but it is blank; it does not write any name of files whose mimeType is "image/png", though there are more than 100 png images files with  mimetype 'image/png':

```
var logFile = space.childByNamePath("book.txt");
if (logFile == null)
{
   logFile = space.createFile("book.txt");
}
if (logFile != null)
{
  var docs = search.luceneSearch("content.mimetype:'image/png'");
   var log = "";
   for (var i=0; i<docs.length; i++)
   {
      log += "Name: " + docs[i].name + "\tPath: " + docs[i].displayPath + "\r\n";
   }
   logFile.content += log;
}
```

Any suggestion what is the wrong with this code. I have put this code inside "company home>Data Dictionary>script" and I am running this script from "company home>Sites" which is root of all contents. Hence it is the root of all folders which contains images files.
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try using this may help you

```
 search.luceneSearch('+PATH:"/app:company_home//*" +@\\{http\\://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0\\}content.mimetype:text/plain');
```

> content.mimetype:text/plain

please specify your mimetype here

you can find more information from [documentation](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-4673-search#jive_content_id_Finding_nodes_by_content_mimetype)

Comment: Thanks Vikash , your search query runs perfectly and gives me the accurate search result - not matter from which folder I run this script . Thanks again !!

Answer (score 1):

The namespace ("cm:") is missing in your query string. Try this:

```
  var docs = search.luceneSearch("@cm\\:content.mimetype:\"image/png\"");
   var log = "";
   for (var i=0; i<docs.length; i++)
   {
      log += "Name: " + docs[i].name + "\tPath: " + docs[i].displayPath + "\r\n";
   }
```

Comment: you should check your query using node browser (/share/page/console/admin-console/node-browser) or java script console.

Comment: Hello Heiko, Your script is also perfectly fine as it returns the exact result. thank you for your help !!